# validate input in command line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create a login panel in the command line using python. so if the user does not insert any `username`, the cursor should remain on the same line but I should get an error on the next line.

I tried:

```
while True:
  input1  = input('username: ')
  if len(input1) == 0:
    print("Sorry, your response was not loud enough.")
    continue

  input2 = stdiomask.getpass('pasword: ')
  if len(input2) == 0:
    print("Sorry, your response was not loud enough.")
    continue

  input3 = stdiomask.getpass('cnf password: ')
  if len(input3) == 0:
    print("Sorry, your response was not loud enough.")
    continue
```

But since I'm using `while` loop so if I'm not inserting password I have to insert username again which I don't want also if I don't insert a username, the username is prompted on next line after showing error. so Is there any way to handle these situations?

something like this:

```
F:\new_file\file> python main.py
? username: # cursor remains here until a username is inserted
> Invalid input # error is prmpted on next line
```

Comment: try to use recursion, posted sample code

Answer (score 1):

Try recursion to get input and check if valid. If it is valid then return input else call the same function again

```
def get_input(name, reset=0):
  if reset:
    print(end=f"> Invalid {name}\r", flush=True)
    print(f"\b", end=f"\r{name}: ", flush=True)
  else:
    print(f"{name}: \b", end=f"\r{name}: ", flush=True)
   
  inp = input()
  if len(inp)==0:
    inp = get_input(name, reset=1)
  return inp
input1=get_input('username')
input2=get_input('pasword')
input3=get_input('cnf password')
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked but Is it possible to write input on the same line, i.e if no input is passed, the error is popped on the next line but the cursor remains at the same line and waits for the user to write input.

Comment: added reset logic in answer. check correct if you find it correct

Comment: Still coming on next line.